# Is xsi:nil to be true is empty or null?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, schema, xslt-2.0

As per the spec,  An element may be ·valid· without content if it has the attribute xsi:nil with the value true. so for example,

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <e1 xsi:nil="true"></e1>
</root>
```

If I am checking if the element (e1) contains text or not by something like: `$e1=''` for null elements so will the above xml return true or not? I believe its okay to check if the element is empty or not with xsi:nil and the above will return false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your transformation is schema-aware and the source document is schema-validated, then you can test whether an element has xsi:nil="true" using the fn:nilled() function.

If the XSLT isn't schema-aware then xsi:nil is just like any other attribute. You could use the test

```
e1[@xsi:nil='true' and not(child::node())]
```

The exact test to use depends on exactly what conditions you want to check for. Testing

```
e1[. = '']
```

for example will match all the following;

```
<e1/>
<e1 xsi:nil="true"/> 
<e1><f/></e1>
<e1><!-- x --></e1>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as null in the XML world, so I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Regarding your second sentence, it's true that in any schema-valid document, an element with xsi:nil="true" will have no text node or element node children. It may have comment or processing-instruction children. And in general, not all documents are schema-valid.

Comment: Well the answer to the question "would it be treated as...?" depends on what software is doing the treating. You didn't mention any database software in your question, so if this is a question about some piece of database software, perhaps you should tell us which. No XML software will treat anything as null, because null is not an XML concept.

Comment: How many times do I have to tell you that I don't know what you mean when you say "null"? There is no such thing as a "null element".